# Homotopy Extension Property: necessary and sufficient condition

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

A pair $(X,A)$ of topological spaces is said to have the homotopic extension property if $\forall Y$ topological space, $f:X-> Y$ continuous map and $H:A\times[0,1]\rightarrow Y$ homotopy of $f$, there exists $\tilde H : X\times[0,1]\rightarrow Y$ extending H.

In class we gave the following lemma:

$(X,A)$ has the h.e.p. $\Leftrightarrow X\times[0,1]$ retracts onto $(X\times\{0\})\ \cup\ (A\times[0,1])$

I think I need $A$ to be closed for this to work but I am probably wrong, so I'll sketch my argument for "$\Leftarrow$" so maybe someone can spot my mistake.

If $r$ is said retraction, in class we simply defined $\tilde H$ to be $f\circ r$ for on $r^{-1}(X\times \{0\})$ and $H\circ f$ on $r^{-1}(A\times[0,1])$ and then claimed that this is well defined. However, I can't see how this function would be continuous if not by using the gluing lemma, which needs A to be closed in X.

Am I missing something?

Thank you.

Comment: The proof for $A$ not necessarily closed is more complicated. See pages 14-15 and Proposition A.18 in [Hatcher](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf).

Comment: @DanteGrevino You should give an official answer to clear the question from the "unanswered" queue. Perhaps you should also give a reference to Strom's original papers because only Hatcher's 2001-version contains A.18.

Comment: @PaulFrost I agree with you, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proof for $A$ not necessarily closed is more complicated. See pages 14-15 and Proposition A.18 in [Hatcher](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf), which is due to [Strøm](https://www.mscand.dk/article/view/10877) (Theorem 2 and Lemma 3).